# runtime error : addition of unsigned offset

Tags: c++, error-handling, runtime-error

I was running this code for maximal square problem on leetcode , I got the following error

Line 1034: Char 34: runtime error: addition of unsigned offset to 0x6080000000a0 overflowed to 0x608000000088 (stl_vector.h)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1043:34

following is the code

```
 bool canBeExpanded(int c_row,int c_col,int sidelength,vector<vector<char>> matrix){
     for(int i=c_row;i>c_row-sidelength;i--)
         if(matrix[i][c_col]==0)
             return false;
      for(int i=c_col;i>c_col-sidelength;i--)
         if(matrix[c_row][i]==0)
             return false;
     return true;
     
 }
int maximalSquare(vector<vector<char>>& matrix) {
    int rows = matrix.size();
    int columns = matrix[0].size();
    int Area[rows][columns];
    int c_row,c_col,maxArea = 0;
    for(c_row = 0;c_row<rows;c_row++)
        for(c_col=0;c_col<columns;c_col++)
            if(c_row==0||c_col==0)
                Area[c_row][c_col]=matrix[c_row][c_col];
     for(c_row = 1;c_row<rows;c_row++)
        for(c_col=1;c_col<columns;c_col++)
        {
          if(Area[c_row-1][c_col-1]&&canBeExpanded(c_row,c_col,sqrt(Area[c_row-1][c_col-1])+1,matrix))
              Area[c_row][c_col] = Area[c_row-1][c_col-1] + 2*sqrt(Area[c_row-1][c_col-1])+1;
            maxArea = max(maxArea,Area[c_row][c_col]);
        }
    return maxArea;
}
```

Comment: You're using a negative subscript somewhere. Consider what happens when `canBeExpanded` is called with the sidelength greater that `c_row` or `c_col`.

Comment: `int Area[rows][columns];` is Undefined Behaviour. What aren't you using `vector` here?

Comment: thank you guys , 
here **matrix is a char type vector** I thought it to be int , I solved this problem and the code is working now